# In time t, a dog does 3 jumps whereas a fox does 5. If distance covered in a jump by a dog is thrice that of the fox, find ratio of speed of dog : fox

Tags: contest-math, ratio, mental-arithmetic

This looks (and I think it is) a pretty simple problem.

My reasoning is as follows :

```
In time t, the dog does 3 jumps
In time t, the fox does 5 jumps

In one jump let the fox cover k units of distance
therefore, in one jump, the dog covers 3k units of distance

In time t, dog covers 3 * 3k = 9k units of distance
In time t, fox covers 5 * k units of distance
Since time is constant, ratio of speeds of dog : fox = 9 : 5
```

I have pored over this problem and the solution for a long time, the reason being that in the answer key, the answer is stated as 3 : 5. Can someone explain whether my reasoning is flawed or the answer key is wrong ?

[This is the picture of the question and the options, the correct option according the answer key is marked with a black circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TR9sa.jpg)

Comment: The official answer seems wrong to me. I agree with your answer.

Comment: The answer is given wrong

Comment: you did right thing

Comment: @MathLover so it seems.

Comment: Should we add the solution as a answer ?